# Check if any field is different from database value

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfquery

After I submit a form, I need to check if any field in the database table changed. If changed I create a new record, if not, I don't do anything. I can't just update the record.

Is there a way to do it without checking every single field like the code below?

```
<cfquery name="getData" datasource="myDS">
  Select * From table Where ID = #form.ID#
</cfquery>
<Cfset changed = false />
<!-- Check every field -->
<cfif form.data1 neq getData.data1>
   <cfset changed = true />
</cfif>
<cfif form.data2 neq getData.data2>
   <cfset changed = true />
</cfif>
<cfif form.data3 neq getData.data3>
   <cfset changed = true />
</cfif>
...
```

Thanks

Comment: You could do it in the query itself. Don't forget to use queryparams. Like `AND data1 = <cfqueryparam value="#form.data1# cfsqltype="yourtype"> .... `. Then `<cfset changed =  getData.recordcount GT 0/>`.

Comment: Are you trying to compare all the fields in the DB? Are there any fields in the DB that are going to be skipped?

Comment: What type of database?

Comment: If this is for some sort of audit trail, you might also be able to use a TRIGGER instead of doing this in CF. Also, nothing to do with the question, but be sure the actual query uses `<cfqueryparam value="#form.ID#" cfsqltype="....">` to avoid sql injection.

Comment: This most probably shouldn't be done in CF; This is an issue that most databases have solved already. But the method totally depends on the DBMS in use.

Comment: *I can't just update the record.* Why? Are you trying to populate an audit/history table?

Answer (score 3):

Might depend on what database you are using but you should be able to do a query that will insert if the data does not exist.

As an example I just tested this against Oracle 12c using CF2016 Enterprise and it creates a new record if the data does not exist.

```
<cfquery name="Testing" datasource="Test">
    INSERT INTO TESTTABLE (DATA1, DATA2, DATA3)
    SELECT  <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Data1#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />, <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Data2#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />, <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Data3#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT DATA1, DATA2, DATA3 FROM TESTTABLE WHERE DATA1 = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Data1#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />, 
    AND DATA2 = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Data2#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" /> AND DATA3 = <cfqueryparam value="#Form.Data3#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />)
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain this a little further? Why are you allowing a form to be submitted with changed data if you can't update the record itself? If you click `Save`, then compare the form data with the query data and have the action call a `Create` function when the data is different.

Let's say you have a thing query and form:

```
<cfquery name="myThing">
    SELECT 
        thing_id,
        thing_name,
        thing_foo
    FROM 
        things 
    where 
        thingID = <cfqueryparam value="#url.thingID#">
</cfquery>

<form> 
    <input type="hidden" name="thing_id" value="#myThing.thing_id#">
    <input type="text" name="thing_name" value="#myThing.thing_name#">
    <input type="text" name="thing_foo" value="#myThing.thing_foo#">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you need to check the submitted data against what's already in the database, you can just run the query again on the form processing page and compare those values against the submitted form values. This example assumes you named the form fields the same as the database table columns.

```
<cfset delta = false>
<cfloop item="key" collection="#myThing#">
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, key)>
        <cfif form[key] NEQ myThing[key]>
            <cfset delta = true>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

If any values differ, then create a new record. No idea what you need to do when the submitted values haven't changed.

```
<cfif delta>
    <!--- Create a new record. --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ --->
</cfif>
```

I've also seen it done where the original values are stored in hidden form fields and submitted along with the editable form fields. You could do this, but there's no guarantee that the values in the DB haven't been changed between you rendering the form and then submitting it.

You'll still have some challenge of how to tell if the DB values have changed on the way to the DB, but I'm not sure if you need so granular a check.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the cfquery to check the table having the existing data or not. If not having the same data means we can Insert the form. The following code may related to your scenario.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form,"Submit")>
    <cfquery name="checkFormExisting" datasource="myDSN">
        SELECT * 
        FROM USERS 
        WHERE data1  = <cfqueryparam value="#form.data1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
            OR data2 = <cfqueryparam value="#form.data2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
            OR data3 = <cfqueryparam value="#form.data3#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    </cfquery>

    <cfif checkFormExisting.recordCount EQ 0>
        INSERT INTO 
            USERS (
                data1,data2,data3
                ) 
                VALUES (
                    <cfqueryparam value="#form.data1#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#form.data2#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">,
                    <cfqueryparam value="#form.data3#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
                )
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Hope, you're asking like the above code for your scenario.

Comment: No, using `OR` would check if *any* field contained the same data values. Based on the description they want to check if data for a *specific* record ID has changed.

Comment: @Ageax I've noticed his description `I need to check if any field in the database table changed. If changed I create a new record, if not, I don't do anything.` So that I thought he asked to check the form fields not only the ID.

Comment: And he asked that the `Is there a way to do it without checking every single field like the code below?`. So that I'm trying to answer like the above.

Comment: @SathishChellandurai - I suspect that's just a poor/ambiguous wording choice. Notice their query example filters on a specific record ID:  `Where ID = #form.ID#`?  While I suppose it's possible, checking if *any* field - in *any* record - contains a matching value is a far less likely scenario ...

Comment: To be clear - the question is how to check a *single* record to see if any of the column values have changed. The query above checks ANY record.